# Does this circuit do anything?

Tags: circuit-analysis, zener

I think I am failing to understand how a zener diode works. Please let me know what you believe will happen if I were to make this circuit.

[image]

Comment: Your schematic is illegible. If those 'H's on the left are earth symbols then please point them down to the ground.

Comment: yeah, I mean, generally, hand-drawn schematics *can* be alright, but this one is just too badly drawn. Why did you even pick a caligraphic pencil shape?

Comment: If those diodes with a Z in them are zeners, please find the correct symbol [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zener_diode#/media/File:Zener_diode_symbol-2.svg)

Comment: You can’t build it because there’s not enough detail in the badly drawn circuit diagram. Please do better, much better.

Comment: Btw for whomever can read my writing and can see I specified all RELEVANT data for my question. You have resistance values and the voltage the zener flops at.

Comment: Thank you huisman for taking a moment to educate me.

Comment: @Justin:  No one has posted an answer as yet.  They've all been comments aimed at helping you get your question into answerable shape.

Comment: @Justin Further education, let me show you the way we tend to do things round here. It works best if you use the right tools for the job. In this case, it means using the schematic editor provided when you post. Edit your post, then edit the schematic I've started, I'm sure you'll get the hang of the controls quite quickly, they're as intuitive or better than most schematic editors I've used. Make sure the zeners are the right way round for what you intend, they drop 0.7v one way, and the zener voltage the other way.

Comment: @JRE I think it is quite obvious the emphasis is on "**horrible** answers" in Justin's comment. I think bottom-line these comments are intended being helpful, but calling someone's first(?) electrical drawing **badly** drawn is not the most encouraging approach

Comment: @Huisman:  Correct about the horrible part.

Comment: Unfortunately, CircuitLab doesn't work on smart phones, and from the screenshot that's what Justin is using.

Answer (score 3):

The circuit diagram editor (CircuitLab) built into the site is also a simulator.  I'm going to use that simulator to see what your circuit does.

Here's what your circuit looks like when drawn in CircuitLab:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX9D0F.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

That circuit gives a pretty much linear voltage to the load:

[image]

The voltage over the load pretty much just follows the source voltage.  It is scaled a bit, and there's a small range at the very start where the voltage across the load stays at zero because the source voltage isn't high enough to make any of the diodes conduct.

All of your diodes are in the normal, forward biased condition.  That means that the Zener voltage doesn't come into play at all.  The diodes all have about 0.7 volts across them.

If I flip all of your diodes into the reverse biased condition, then it would look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxXNXI.png)</sup>

That gives you a voltage plot like this:

[image]

That's more interesting, but probably not what you expected.  The "knee" is at 150V, which is the sum of the Zener voltage for D2 and D4.  Only those two are actually doing anything.

D1 is effectively short circuited by R1.

D2 and D3 are effectively in parallel, so you only get the Zener voltage of a single diode - they act like a single diode.

Just to make it clear, here's how Zener diodes work:

1. Forward bias, normal diode:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqgz6o.png)</sup>

That circuit produces this voltage plot:

[image]

Notice the voltage across the bottom is the source voltage, while the voltage up and down is the voltage across the diode.  It "snaps over" at around 0.7 volts.  The rated Zener voltage of the diode doesn't come into play.

2. Reverse bias, Zener diode

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRBfG3.png)</sup>

That circuit produces this voltage plot:

[image]

Again, source voltage along the bottom and diode voltage up and down.

Notice that it "snaps over" at about 5.1V (the rated Zener voltage of the diode.) That's the typical Zener action, and it only occurs when the diode is reverse biased.  A normal diode won't conduct at all when reverse biased.  A Zener diode doesn't conduct in reverse bias, either - until the reverse bias voltage exceeds the Zener limit for that diode.

Now, for comparison, here's a simple version of your circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fblREN.png)</sup>

Because the order of the diode and the load are reversed, we get a different looking plot.

[image]

The voltage at the load starts at zero because the Zener diode isn't conducting.  Once the source voltage reaches 5.1V, the diode starts conducting and the voltage across the load begins to go up.  It starts at zero, and follows the source voltage.  The voltage across the load is: \$V_{source} - 5.1V\$

I hope that (long) explanation helps you understand Zener diodes a little better.

---

When tackling a new subject, it is usually better to start with a simple example and work up rather than throw together something complicated and try to work down to the simple things.

Comment: Thank you so much! I am going to read this several times. I will be sure to learn something so I can make use of it with joy! I am really wanting to make a welder that can be hooked up to any voltage up to 450v AC or DC. I am a programmer and I want to build a diag welder with sensors in many portions of the welder. Ill record myself making erroneous welds and use my sensor readings and AI assistance to find patterns in the systems readings which I can use to make live corrections to the welders arc. Etc